# clang-format with perforce changes

Tags: perforce, llvm-clang, clang-format

Is there a way to have clang-format-diff.py work with perforce? I know that it supports svn. The problem I guess is here is that p4 diff doesn't seem to have a way to feed in a custom diffing tool (except through the p4config).

Answer (score 1):

Set `P4DIFF` to be the name of your custom diffing tool.

```
p4 set P4DIFF=whatever_diff_tool
p4 diff
```